# Why this set is a $R/\mathfrak m$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I'm reading this PDF: [Discrete Valuation Rings and Function Fields of Curves](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/oldwebpages/Math683Fall2013/dvr.pdf). I'm trying to understand in this theorem why $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ is a $R/\mathfrak m$-module (see number 4 below).

I don't think $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ is an ideal of $R/\mathfrak m$, it's not even a subset.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: because $m$ annihilates $m/m^2$

Comment: Not all modules are ideals - think vector spaces as the key example here. $R/m$ is a field - does it make sense to multiply elements of $m/m^2$ by elements of $R/m$? You can certainly multiply by elements of $R$ - is the result independent of the coset? Does $m/m^2$ satisfy the axioms for a vector space over the field $R/m$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why an R-module is an R/I-module precisely when it is annihilated by I?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182162/why-an-r-module-is-an-r-i-module-precisely-when-it-is-annihilated-by-i)

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma**. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ and let $M$ be an $R$-module such that $I$ annihilates $M$. Then $M$ is an $R/I$ module (See [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182162/why-an-r-module-is-an-r-i-module-precisely-when-it-is-annihilated-by-i), for proof).
 Note hat $m$ annihilates $m/m^2$.
All ideals are modules, but it is not true that all modules are ideals; The fact is that if a **subset** of $R$ is a module it will be an ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is not a subset of $R/\mathfrak{m}$. However, for any ring $A$, the definition of "$A$-module" makes no requirement that it be a subset of $A$, so your observation is irrelevant to the question.

Informally, an $A$-module $N$ is just an abelian group equipped with a notion of "multiplication by elements of $A$". That is, we should be able to add elements of $N$ together (e.g., $n_1+n_2$) and multiply an element of $N$ by an element of $A$ (e.g., $an$), and these operations should be compatible (e.g., $a(n_1+n_2)=an_1+an_2$).

We can add elements of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ together as usual; it is an abelian group quotiented by a subgroup. The addition operation on such cosets is
$$(m_1+\mathfrak{m}^2)+(m_2+\mathfrak{m}^2)=(m_1+m_2)+\mathfrak{m^2}$$
Now you can check that this is a well-defined operation of multiplying an element of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ by an element of $R/\mathfrak{m}$ (i.e., it doesn't depend on the coset representatives $r$ and $m$ that are chosen):
$$(r+\mathfrak{m})\cdot (m+\mathfrak{m}^2)=rm+\mathfrak{m}^2$$
This demonstrates that $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is an $R/\mathfrak{m}$-module.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm having problems to prove this operation is well-defined. Could give me some hint how to proceed?