# $\operatorname{Hom}_{R/I}(I/I^2, M)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_R(I,M)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules

In the proof of Proposition 6.1.8(d) of Qing Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, the following identification between two $\operatorname{Hom}$-modules is stated without proof, and I'd like to clarify the details.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $I\subseteq R$ be an ideal, and $M$ be an $R$-module. Then the claim is that $$\operatorname{Hom}_{R/I}(I/I^2, M)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_R(I,M).$$

This statement should mean that any $R/I$-linear map $I/I^2\rightarrow M$ comes from a $R$-linear map $I\rightarrow M$. I tried to consider the SES of $R$-modules $$0\rightarrow I^2\rightarrow I\rightarrow I/I^2\rightarrow 0$$ and then apply the left-exact contravariant $\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(-, M)$ to obtain $$0\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_{R}(I/I^2, M)\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_{R}(I,M)\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_{R}(I^2, M)$$

where the image of the second homomorphism is the kernel of the third. I feel like the desired identification should follow from here, but I'm having trouble seeing what's going on.

Comment: I am a bit confused. If we pick $R=\mathbb{Z}, I = 2\mathbb{Z}, M=\mathbb{Z}$, then we have $$ \mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(2\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}. $$ On the other hand, we have $$ \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}(2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \{ 0\} $$ assuming that you can find some $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-module structure on the integers.

Comment: Another thing that I do not understand is what kind of $R/I$-structure you put on $I/I^2$. Wouldn't you just get the trivial module? And how is $M$ a $R/I$-module?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven The structure is induced from the $R$ module structure on $I$ as in $I/I^2$ $I$ is annihilated by $I$. I am however quite sure that one needs $M$ to be an $R/I$ module from the beginning as there is no clear $R/I$ module structure on it (This should also be where the example you give fails).

Comment: @LT1918 I don't understand, the induced $R/I$-module structure is simply trivial, isn't it?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven. It does not have to be trivial. Even in your example $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I=2 \mathbb{Z}$ the structure is non trivial as you have $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$ and the structure is simply $\mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$ acting on itself by multiplication.

Comment: @LT1918 Sorry, I completely missed the point... thanks for the clarification.

Comment: As others have pointed out, M needs to be an R/I-module and then it is just adjunction.

Comment: Yes, $M$ needs to be a $R/I$-module, and I just missed this detail when I gave the question. In this case, we can also view $M$ as a $R$-module via restriction of scalars along the quotient map. However, general $R$-modules need not be $R/I$-modules, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182162/why-an-r-module-is-an-r-i-module-precisely-when-it-is-annihilated-by-i).

Answer (score 1):

You can see the answer for this from the short exact sequence you have written down although I believe you need $M$ to be an $R/I$ module. (I also don't see how the statement makes sense if you don't have this) Then note that $\text{Hom}_{R/I}(I/I^2,M)=\text{Hom}_{R}(I/I^2,M)$ so it is enough to show that the image of the last map is 0. But now for any $f \in \text{Hom}_{R}(I,M) $ you have that $f(I^2)$=0. Indeed for any $x \in I^2 $ you have that $x$ is a sum of terms of the form $x_{i}y_{i}$ for $x_{i} \ , y_{i} \in I$ but you have $f(x_{i}y_{i})=x_{i}f(y_{i}) \in IM$ but as $M$ is an $R/I$ module $M = M/IM$ so that you have $f(x_{i}y_{i})=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion from Cranium Clamp's comment to use adjunction, here's another way to see what's going on:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Hom}_{B/I}(I/I^2, M) &\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{B/I}(I\otimes_B (B/I), M)\\
&\cong \operatorname{Hom}_B(I, \operatorname{Hom}_{B/I}(B/I, M))\\
&\cong \operatorname{Hom}_B(I, M)
\end{align*}